# hello.cpp cannot be compiled in eosio

Tags: eos

I just followed the tutorial to make a smart contracts. Everything went fine until I compiled hello.cpp in the tutorial. It is a simple "hello world" program. But I waited for 5 minutes and the compiling never ended. I built in ubuntu and cdt version is 1.3.2. Any tips?

I tried to follow official demo hello. [link](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/your-first-contract) . When I tried to compile hello.cpp as *eosio-cpp -o hello.wasm hello.cpp -v*, I got stuck here.

```
 clang version 7.0.0 (https://github.com/eosio/clang.git 5647a49355fbcffd0bc940a7b857318f5bc84beb) (https://github.com/eosio/llvm e0f9c15ad4199a628dda25df589cad1634d01c5b)
Target: wasm32
Thread model: single
InstalledDir: /usr/opt/eosio.cdt/1.3.2/bin
"/usr/opt/eosio.cdt/1.3.2/bin/clang-7" -cc1 -triple wasm32 -emit-obj -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name hello.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mthread-model single -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -ffreestanding -fuse-init-array -target-cpu generic -fvisibility hidden -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=gdb -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -v -coverage-notes-file /home/ubuntu/contracts/hello/hello.gcno -resource-dir /usr/opt/eosio.cdt/1.3.2/lib/clang/7.0.0 -D BOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -D BOOST_EXCEPTION_DISABLE -I /usr/opt/eosio.cdt/1.3.2/bin/../include/libcxx -I 
/usr/opt/eosio.cdt/1.3.2/bin/../include/libc -I 
/usr/opt/eosio.cdt/1.3.2/bin/../include -isysroot 
/usr/opt/eosio.cdt/1.3.2/bin/../ -internal-isystem 
/usr/opt/eosio.cdt/1.3.2/bin/..//include/c++/v1 -internal-isystem 
/usr/opt/eosio.cdt/1.3.2/bin/..//include -O3 --std=c++17 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /home/ubuntu/contracts/hello -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 189 -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-threadsafe-statics -fobjc-runtime=gnustep -fno-common -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -vectorize-loops -vectorize-slp -load /usr/opt/eosio.cdt/1.3.2/bin/eosio_plugin.so -load /usr/opt/eosio.cdt/1.3.2/bin/LLVMEosioApply.so -mllvm -use-cfl-aa-in-
```

codegen=both -o hello.wasm -x c++ hello.cpp
    clang -cc1 version 7.0.0 based upon LLVM 7.0.0svn default target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    ignoring nonexistent directory 
    "/usr/opt/eosio.cdt/1.3.2/bin/..//include/c++/v1"
    ignoring nonexistent directory 
    "/usr/opt/eosio.cdt/1.3.2/bin/..//usr/local/include"
    ignoring nonexistent directory 
    "/usr/opt/eosio.cdt/1.3.2/lib/clang/7.0.0/include"
    ignoring nonexistent directory 
    "/usr/opt/eosio.cdt/1.3.2/bin/..//usr/include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/opt/eosio.cdt/1.3.2/bin/../include"
  as it is a non-system directory that duplicates a system directory
    #include "..." search starts here:
    #include <...> search starts here:
     /usr/opt/eosio.cdt/1.3.2/bin/../include/libcxx
     /usr/opt/eosio.cdt/1.3.2/bin/../include/libc
     /usr/opt/eosio.cdt/1.3.2/bin/../include
    End of search list.

Comment: Add more details that clears your questiion..`@Raif Ma`

Comment: [github](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/issues/123) I got answer from eos github. The problem is caused by VM setting. If the VM only has one CPU, the issue happens. After I changed the VM setting, the problem was gone.